# How to find next line character in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Need to find next line character from a table in Teradata

Sample query for reference I tried.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'ABC
DEF' AS DESCRIPTION) T
WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'||'0A'xc||'%'
;
```

Comment: Particularly if the data source was Windows, the "next line" character may have been sent as '0D'xc not '0A'xc.  Use CHAR2HEXINT function to double check.

Answer (score 0):

Because, as @Fred mentioned, there is the likelihood you will need to search for line-feed `'0A'xc`, carriage-return `'0D'xc`, or a combination of both, it may be more elegant to solve with `REGEXP_SIMILAR()`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(DESCRIPTION, '.*(\n|\r|\n\r|\r\n).*') = 1
```